# How do I turn ON/OFF input with type = checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have an input type checkbox that is configured for on/off purposes, with values true/false accordingly. I want to be able to turn it off and on whenever i call a function using javascript.

The checkbox looks like this:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="hidden" id="i" value="{{bc}}"/>
    <input type="checkbox" data-type="bc-s" name="onoffswitch{{itemID}}-age" class="onoffswitch-checkbox bc-manage" id="asd" {{#bc}}checked{{/bc}} />
    <label id="sbc" class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch{{itemID}}-age">
        <div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
        <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

I want to turn it on/off using this:

```
function disregardSave () {
   container.find("#asd").prop('checked', data.bc);
}
```

but failed then tried this:

```
function disregardSave () {
   container.find("#asd").val(data.bc);
}
```

and nothing works. I don't know why.

Comment: `id` of `checkbox` is `asd`; so the code has to be `container.find("#asd").prop('checked', !data.bc);` assuming that `container` is a jquery parent object

Comment: ive updated the question, still not working :(

Comment: how you are getting `container`? can you please show us that js code?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What `container` here? If your checkbox has id why not you try this `$("#asd").prop('checked', data.bc)`

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox's id is "asd" so have you tried :

```
$('#asd').prop("checked", true);
```

This is my way to change checkbox status in jquery